# How do I simplify this matrix equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I'm working on a larger proof and am struggling with one portion in which I need get a matrix equation into a desired form. Here is that problem:

I have a matrix equation (left side) that needs to be formatted into another form (right side). I've simplified the left side as much as I could but can't seem to get it to the match the right side. Note that Q and R are invertible. H is not. I've also used MATLAB to verify that the two equations are indeed the same.

[image]

How would I go about obtaining this desired form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I got it.

$$
\begin{aligned}
(Q &- QH^T(R+HQH^T)^{-1}HQ)H^TR^{-1}) 
\\
&= ((QH^T(R+HQH^T)^{-1})(QH^T(R+HQH^T)^{-1})^{-1} QH^TR^{-1} 
\\&\quad -QH^T(R+HQH^T)^{-1}HQH^TR^{-1} )
\\&= (QH^T(R+HQH^T)^{-1})\cdot
\underbrace{((QH^T(R+HQH^T)^{-1})^{-1} QH^TR^{-1}-HQH^TR^{-1})}_{=I}
\\&= QH^T(R+HQH^T)^{-1}
\end{aligned}
$$

Where for the last equal sign this is used:
\begin{aligned}
(&QH^T(R+HQH^T)^{-1})^{-1} QH^TR^{-1}-HQH^TR^{-1} 
\\&=
(R+HQH^T)(QH^T)^{-1}QH^T R^{-1}-HQH^TR^{-1} 
\\&=
(R+HQH^T)R^{-1}-HQH^TR^{-1} 
\\&=
I+HQH^TR^{-1}-HQH^TR^{-1} 
\\& = I
\end{aligned}

Comment: You did. Beat me to it!

Comment: Only by a few seconds ^^. But maybe yours is more readable.

Comment: I can't seem to follow this explanation either. How do we get to the final derived form?

Comment: Because the expression after the expression you are looking for is the identity matrix. I will make it more explicit.

Comment: It looks like I had forgotten that the inverse of a matrix product is equal to the product of each matrix (reverse ordered). Great illustration.

Comment: One more question... how exactly did you go from line 1 to line 2? I'm having a difficult time performing that step.

Comment: Where did you get the $$((QH^T(R+HQH^T)^{-1})(QH^T(R+HQH^T)^{-1})^{-1}$$?

Comment: @hal4math I was able to determine that, I just don't understand how you were able to decompose an identity matrix into that. Is it some special property? $$(A^{-1}A^{-1})^{-1} = I?$$

Comment: @hal4math Apologies, I got lost in the braces. I thought that last inverse was inverting the entire quantity, not just the second term.

Comment: ah no problem. Maybe I delete this comments then, to clean up this thread.

Answer (score 2):

This originates from the relationship between block matrix inverse and [Schur complements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement). In general, given a block matrix
$$
\pmatrix{A&B\\ C&D}
$$
where $A$ and $D$ are nonsingular matrices of probably different sizes, we can write it as a product of block matrices in two different ways:
$$
\pmatrix{A&B\\ C&D}=
\begin{cases}
\pmatrix{I&0\\ CA^{-1}&I}\pmatrix{A&0\\ 0&D-CA^{-1}B}\pmatrix{I&A^{-1}B\\ 0&I},\\
\\
\pmatrix{I&BD^{-1}\\ 0&I}\pmatrix{A-BD^{-1}C&0\\ 0&D}\pmatrix{I&0\\ D^{-1}C&I}.
\end{cases}
$$
It follows that
$$
\pmatrix{X&Y\\ Z&W}:=\pmatrix{A&B\\ C&D}^{-1}=
\begin{cases}
\pmatrix{I&-A^{-1}B\\ 0&I}\pmatrix{A^{-1}&0\\ 0&(D-CA^{-1}B)^{-1}}\pmatrix{I&0\\ -CA^{-1}&I},\\
\\
\pmatrix{I&0\\ -D^{-1}C&I}\pmatrix{(A-BD^{-1}C)^{-1}&0\\ 0&D^{-1}}\pmatrix{I&-BD^{-1}\\ 0&I}.
\end{cases}
$$
Therefore, by comparing the two ways of calculating $W$ or $Z$, we get
\begin{align}
(D-CA^{-1}B)^{-1}&=W=D^{-1}+D^{-1}C(A-BD^{-1}C)^{-1}BD^{-1},\tag{1}\\
-(D-CA^{-1}B)^{-1}CA^{-1}&=Z=-D^{-1}C(A-BD^{-1}C)^{-1}.\tag{2}
\end{align}
Substitute $(1)$ into $(2)$, we obtain
$$
\left[D^{-1}+D^{-1}C(A-BD^{-1}C)^{-1}BD^{-1}\right]CA^{-1}
=D^{-1}C(A-BD^{-1}C)^{-1}.
$$
Now, the identity in question follows by putting $A=R,\ B=-H,\ C=H^T$ and $D=Q^{-1}$.

Comment: That is definitely more illuminating than just hacking it out.

Answer (score 1):

Sketch:

Replace $K$ by $L:=Q^{-1}KR$ and re-write the two expressions.

Replace $Q$ by $S:=HQH^{T}$, and re-write the two expressions.

It will suffice to prove
$$I-(R+S)^{-1}S=(R+S)^{-1}R$$
and then multiply by $H^{T}$.

Comment: I don't really follow. What is the intuition in replacing matrices with matrix products? Regarding you last equation involving the identity matrix, is that some known property?

Comment: @Izzo: (i) Just looking at your expressions it's clear that the $Q$ in front and $R^{-1}$ at the end just make for confusion, so get rid of them (ii) it's then clear that $Q$ only appears as $HQH^{T}$ so simplify by calling that term $S$. And then it boils down to showing $R+S$ is the inverse of $R+S$.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be as per @ancientmathematician's tip:

$$
 K = (Q - Q{H^T}(HQ{H^T} + R)^{-1}HQ){H^T}R^{-1} \\
   = Q{H^T}(I - (HQ{H^T} + R)^{-1}HQ{H^T})R^{-1} \\
   = Q{H^T}((HQ{H^T} + R)^{-1}R)R^{-1} \\
   = Q{H^T}(HQ{H^T} + R)^{-1},
$$

since $(HQ{H^T} + R)^{-1}(HQ{H^T} + R) = I$, so, after rearranging, we get $I - (HQ{H^T} + R)^{-1}HQ{H^T} = (HQ{H^T} + R)^{-1}R,$ which we substitute in the third line of the first chain of equations to get the desired result.